# Configure static routes on Windows

Tags: windows, networking

There is a `netsh` and a `route` command on Windows. From their help text it looks like both can be used to configure static routes.  When should you use one and not the other?  Is IPv6 a distinguishing factor here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`route` is a very old and basic tool for displaying and modifying the entries in the local IP routing table while `netsh` is the newer, more robust command-line **scripting utility** that allows you to, either locally or **remotely**, manipulate the network configuration.

`netsh` has a zillion more features than route; it can even save your current settings as a script that another instance of netsh can parse. Check out [Using `netsh`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx) to see the giant feature set and compare it to how very basic and simple `routes` is.